# Special Datatypes used in Domain Classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Imagine for example you want to store amounts of money in a domain class. A simple approach would be something like this:

```
class Account {
    BigDecimal amount
}
```

but what if you don't want to handle your amount as simple `BigDecimal` but as `Money` type on which you have for instance defined some additional convenience methods like currency conversions.

So something like

```
class Account {
    Money amount
}
```

would result in getting it stored in another table.

So my question is: how can I define a class `Money` which would be stored as BigDecimal in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [an embedded class](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#gormComposition) to have an seperate `Money` class which is stored within your `Account` table.

```
class Account {
    Money amount
    static embedded = ['amount']
}

class Money {
    BigDecimal amount

    def asDollar() {
        amount
    }

    def asEuro() {
        amount / 1.3
    }
}
```

Put both classes (`Account` and `Money`) into one groovy file within your domain folder to avoid the creation of an extra table for money.

Another approach would be to use a [custome hibernate type](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customHibernateTypes).